# What does [ctb] stand for?

Tags: publications, terminology

This [R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/index.html) f.x. states:

"Kurt Hornik [ctb]"

I assume this abbreviation is coming from academic publishing - hence why I ask it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ctb = Contributor.

It's not so much about academic publishing, but (academic/open source) software. One has authors and contributors. Contributors added a bit of code, but presumably did not contribute to the overall design efforts.